# Inserting data into sql table in Eclipse EE

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I'm confused on how to send data to my database in Eclipse. I have Eclipse EE and I set up my database development correctly but I don't understand how to actually send the data in the database. I tried writing the mysql code inline with the Java but that didn't work so I'm assuming I'm doing it way wrong.

```
public void sendTime() {
    String time = new java.util.Date();
    INSERT INTO 'records' ('id', 'time') VALUES (NULL, time);
}
```

Comment: This guide might help you get started. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Comment: Thank you! I'll read that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to do the following:

1) Install MySQL (presumably already done)

2) Download a MySQL JDBC driver and make sure it's in your Eclipse project's CLASSPATH.

3) Write your program to use JDBC.  For example (untested):

```
 private Connection connect = null;
 private Statement statement = null;
 try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connect =
      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/xyz?"
          + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");
      String query = "INSERT INTO records (id, time) VALUES (?, ?)";
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      preparedStmt.setInt (1, null);
      preparedStmt.setDate (2, new java.util.Date());
      preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      ...
    }
```

Here are a couple of good tutorials:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I followed the tutorial to connect to the database like so
http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Setup_MySQL_DB_in_Eclipse

Do I still need the code above?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. You must do some form of "connect" (the above is just an example - there are many variations, such as JNDI datasource).  You must also use JDBC syntax (you cannot just write "INSERT" in a Java program - "INSERT" is not a Java keyword).  STRONG SUGGESTION: study at least one of the JDBC tutorials cited in response to your post.

Comment: I've looked at every single link and tried all of the suggestions but none of them work for me. Everything gives me this error when compiling http://pastebin.com/hLSxV3aq @FoggyDay

Answer (score 1):

This is a demo code for database use in JAVA

```
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name","uname","password");

        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        String stmt = "Type your sql INSERT statement here";
        st.execute(stmt);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Here is a quick guide tutorial which you must read :-

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-quick-guide.htm