# Trying to connect to a database in Eclipse ee

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have been trying this for a few hours now but with no success. I downloaded the JDBC driver and it shows that it is one of my referenced libraries under my Package Explorer in Eclipse but every time I try to run my code I get errors. My database is fine as I can change it and view it from the MySQL Command Line Client.

I actually followed a guides directions on how to do it, only replacing the information from their database to information about mine.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class FirstExample {

//JDBC Driver Name and Database URL
final static String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
final static String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_database";

//Database Credentials
static final String USER = "user_one";
static final String PASS = "User_one_password";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        //Register JDBC Driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //Open a Connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to the Database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        //Execute a Query
        System.out.println("Creating Statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        //Extract Data from Result Set
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Retrieve by Column Name
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String first = rs.getString("name");

            //Display Values
            System.out.print("ID: " + id);
            System.out.println("Name: " + first);
        }
        //Clean Up Environment
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        //Handle Errors For JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle Errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //Finally Block used to close resources
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
            //Nothing We Can Do
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (Exception se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }//End Finally Try
    }//End Try
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//End Main

}//End First Example
```

Here is the error I get http://pastebin.com/hLSxV3aq

Comment: You need to provide the error what you are getting while connecting to database.

Comment: ...after closely looking into it, why do you have `i` in `com.mysqli.jdbc.Driver`. It should be `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. Right?

Comment: What version of jdbc driver do you have? Versions >=4.0 do not require the Class.forName

Comment: @lining you're right on that, that's a typo on my part. Unfortunately it did not solve the problem

Comment: @RenéWinkler I have 5.1.34 Should I just remove that line?

Comment: Yes its worth to give it a try

Comment: Then you need to provide the error what you are getting while connecting to the database. That will help us to identify what's wrong?

Comment: I added the error I get as a pastebin link. @RenéWinkler still same error unfortunately

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting data into sql table in Eclipse EE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818152/inserting-data-into-sql-table-in-eclipse-ee)

Comment: 1) This is the same problem you're asking about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818152/inserting-data-into-sql-table-in-eclipse-ee/).  2) Your "pastebin" shows a bunch of XML - how exactly did you get this "error"?  Where is the "error" in that XML???  3) We assume you're creating a simple "Java application" in Eclipse, you've added the MySQL connector .jar to your project's classpath, and you're trying to run/debug "FirstExample" as a "Java Application".  Correct?  If you have any errors - SHOW US THE ERRORS YOU SEE IN ECLIPSE, please!

Comment: @FoggyDay it wasn't a duplicate in my opinion because the way I connected in first question wasn't using JDBC. That's everything that it throws me in the console, it doesn't give me an actual error.